# Android Custom Intent Cannot Start Activity (Yes, I include the DEFAULT category)

Tags: android, android-activity, android-intent

I have searched and searched and cannot seem to find the answer to this specific question about a custom intent.

I have an application with 4 activities, 1 is the main that sets things up and the other 3 represent the different screens I present to the user. I am trying to use custom intents to start the different activities.

Here is my AndroidManifext.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
```

```
<application android:icon="@drawable/icon" android:label="@string/app_name">
    <activity android:name=".Activities.REDB_main" android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:launchMode="singleTop">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
    <activity android:name=".Activities.ChooseCards" android:launchMode="singleTop">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="@string/ACTION_VIEW" />
            <action android:name="@string/ACTION_REFRESH" />
            <category android:name="@string/CATEGORY_SHUFFLE" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
    <activity android:name=".Activities.SelectSets" android:launchMode="singleTop">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="@string/ACTION_VIEW" />
            <action android:name="@string/ACTION_REFRESH" />
            <category android:name="@string/CATEGORY_SELECT_SETS" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
    <activity android:name=".Activities.SelectCards" android:launchMode="singleTop"
        android:permission="android.permission.ACCESS_CHECKIN_PROPERTIES">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="@string/ACTION_VIEW" />
            <action android:name="@string/ACTION_REFRESH" />
            <category android:name="@string/CATEGORY_SELECT_CARDS" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
</application>
```

I create a category for each application and then the two kinds of actions I want it to handle. I know that I could use explicit intents, but since I want to have different actions I figured that making the implicit intents would work better.

I call the first of my real activities from within my main with this:

```
 Intent intent = new Intent().setAction(getString(R.string.ACTION_VIEW));
 intent.addCategory(getString(R.string.CATEGORY_SHUFFLE));
 startActivity(intent);
```

Of course, the reason I am here is because the above can never find the activity that matches the intent. The error messages states the action and category correctly and unless I'm wrong, the above manifest creates the intent-filters correctly.

Searching around online, I always seem to find examples with data also being used. I messed around with adding data just to see if it was necessary but it did not seem to matter.

On a slightly different note, is there a different way I should be controlling the flow of my program besides intents? The reason I have two actions is because 1 switches the view while the other is there to just refresh the data so that when the user switches to the screen later, they don't see it quickly refresh the data but instead just the new stuff.

Answer (score 1):

> I know that I could use explicit intents, but since I want to have different actions I figured that making the implicit intents would work better.

I rather doubt that. Mostly you use `<intent-filter>` when you want things other than your own app to start the component (e.g., third party apps).

Also, I doubt you want `android:launchMode="singleTop"` on all of those. And I am very certain that you do not want `android:permission="android.permission.ACCESS_CHECKIN_PROPERTIES"` on the last one, as you won't be able to launch your own activity then, most likely.

> The error messages states the action and category correctly and unless I'm wrong, the above manifest creates the intent-filters correctly.

I have never seen an Android application use a string resource for a `<category>` element. Perhaps that is contributing to your difficulty. Also, since the `<category>` elements are not doing you any good that I can see (except your `LAUNCHER` one), I am unclear why you put them there.

I suggest that you just drop the `<intent-filter>` elements and use explicit `Intents`.

Answer (score 0):

Don't use resource strings to make intents actions, use `android.intent.action.VIEW` instead